# Python: script's directory

Tags: python, directory

I was looking for a solution, but have not found what I need.

Script path: */dir/to/script/script.py* or *C:\dir\script.py*

Excepted result:

```
$ ./script.py
output: /dir/to/script
$ cd .. && ./script/script.py
output: /dir/to/script
```

Is there any function in os module or something?

---

I mixed solutions and write:

```
print os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

But it's ugly. Is there better way?

Answer (score 15):

os.path.realpath will give you the result:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

Comment: the question asked for the script dirname.  all realpath does is eliminate symbolic links and then return `os.path.abspath`

Comment: it is still fragile and assumes certain things about the cwd and where the script was executed from.  for example,  put `os.chdir('/tmp')` in the line above in the script and this solution can break.