# How to open a file only using its extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, input, io

I have a Python script which opens a specific text file located in a **specific directory** (*working directory*) and perform some actions.

(Assume that if there is a text file in the directory then it will always be no more than one such `.txt` file)

```
with open('TextFileName.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # perform some string manipulation and calculations

    # write some results to a different text file
    with open('results.txt', 'a') as r:
        r.write(someResults)
```

My question is how I can have the script **locate the text (.txt) file in the directory and open it without explicitly providing its name** (i.e. without giving the 'TextFileName.txt'). So, *no arguments* for which text file to open would be required for this script to run.

Is there a way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: script's directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293601/python-scripts-directory)

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisFabre That question is about Python's realpath directory. In my case I am interested in opening a file without explicitly providing its name (i.e. solely based on its file extension) which happens to be in the script's realpath directory. Made some small modifications to the question to make the distinction clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `os.listdir` to get the files in the current directory, and filter them by their extension:

```
import os

txt_files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.txt')]
if len(txt_files) != 1:
    raise ValueError('should be only one txt file in the current directory')

filename = txt_files[0]
```

Comment: That searches the working directory, not the script's directory.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I updated my question since it makes no difference to me if it is the working or the script's directory. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ShadowRanger opening a file with a relative path, as the OP does also opens in the working directory. I'm guessing this is what OP meant.

Comment: @Mureinik You assumed correctly even though I should had made it clearer in my initial post; edited the question so now it should be clear.

Answer (score 7):

You Can Also Use `glob` Which is easier than `os`

```
import glob

text_file = glob.glob('*.txt') 
# wild card to catch all the files ending with txt and return as list of files

if len(text_file) != 1:
    raise ValueError('should be only one txt file in the current directory')

filename = text_file[0]
```

`glob` searches the current directory set by `os.curdir`

You can change to the working directory by setting

`os.chdir(r'cur_working_directory')`

Answer (score 1):

Since Python version 3.4, it is possible to use the great [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) library. It offers a [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) method which makes it easy to filter according to extensions:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(".")  # current directory
extension = ".txt"

file_with_extension = next(path.glob(f"*{extension}"))  # returns the file with extension or None
if file_with_extension:
    with open(file_with_extension):
        ...
```